# Trying to close and open a new window using PyQT(Closed)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Edit*: I don't understand why I got a minus but I'm not an I.T graduate. I'm learning coding by myself.. A lot of terms for programming I don't understand also.. Please be kind..

I'm trying to build a login window using Qt and PyQT.
I tried the one from here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_QBq2L1uzQ

But somehow it's not working.

I'm building my apps on CentOS 6.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'taco_login.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
     _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
         return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

 class Ui_login_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, login_window):
        login_window.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("login_window"))
        login_window.resize(255, 150)
        login_window.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(255, 150))
        login_window.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(255, 150))
        login_window.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QDialog#login_window {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.559, y1:0, x2:0.555, y2:1, stop:0.445455 rgba(48, 48, 48, 255), stop:0.859091 rgba(61, 61, 61, 255), stop:1 rgba(79, 79, 79, 255));\n"
"}"))
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(login_window)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(login_window)
        self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
        self.password_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.password_lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 221, 22))
        self.password_lineEdit.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QWidget {border:none;}"))
        self.password_lineEdit.setInputMask(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.password_lineEdit.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
    self.password_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("password_lineEdit"))
        self.login_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.login_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 91, 17))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.login_btn.setPalette(palette)
        self.login_btn.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.login_btn.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QPushButton#login_btn {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}"))
        self.login_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("login_btn"))
        self.username_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.username_lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 221, 22))
        self.username_lineEdit.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QWidget {border:none;}"))
        self.username_lineEdit.setInputMask(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.username_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("username_lineEdit"))
        self.text_1 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.text_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 0, 141, 25))
        self.text_1.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QTextEdit#text_1{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"    background-color: transparent;\n"
"}\n"
""))
         self.text_1.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
         self.text_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("text_1"))
         self.cancel_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
         self.cancel_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 100, 91, 17))
         palette = QtGui.QPalette()
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
         brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
         palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
         brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
         palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
         brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
         palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
         brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
         palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
         brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
         palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
         brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
         palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
         brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
         palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
         brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
         palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
         brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
         brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
         palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
         self.cancel_btn.setPalette(palette)
         self.cancel_btn.setAutoFillBackground(False)
         self.cancel_btn.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QPushButton#cancel_btn {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}"))
        self.cancel_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("cancel_btn"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.retranslateUi(login_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(login_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, login_window):
        login_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("login_window", "TACO", None))
        self.password_lineEdit.setText(_translate("login_window", "Password", None))
        self.login_btn.setText(_translate("login_window", "Login", None))
        self.username_lineEdit.setText(_translate("login_window", "Username", None))
        self.text_1.setHtml(_translate("login_window", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Sans\'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600; color:#f0f0f0;\">Welcome to TACO!</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.cancel_btn.setText(_translate("login_window", "Cancel", None))

    @QtCore.pyqtSignature("on_cancel_btn_clicked()")
    def Cancel_btn(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    login_window = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_login_window()
    ui.setupUi(login_window)
    login_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At first I tried to close my program using:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSignature("on_cancel_btn_clicked()")
def Cancel_btn(self):
    self.close()
```

But somehow it didn't work.
I also trying to open a new window, will the code below working?

```
@QtCore.pyqtSignature("on_login_btn_clicked()")
def Login_btn(self):
    username = 'usertest':
    password = 'passtest':
    if not username:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Username Missing!')
    elif not password:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Password Missing!')
    else:
        self.AttemptLogin(username, password)

def AttemptLogin(self, username, password):
    t = self.dbu.GetTable()
    print (t)
    for col in t:
        if username == 'usertest':
            if password == 'passtest':
                QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Success!!')
                self.close()
            else:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Incorrect Username or Password')
                return
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use custum dialogs, inherit `QtGui.QDialog`.

Comment: I'm a noob in here.. Can you explain me more about inherit QtGui.QDialog? I don't understand.. I'm not an I.T graduate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance is used to indicate that a class will get all features of its parent class. When you write `class child(parent)` you make `child` inherit from `parent`.

In your code just do this:

```
class Ui_Login(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
```

We call `QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)` so that `Ui_Login()` will be initialized in the same way as `QtGui.QDialog()`

In the `if` statement, `login_window = QtGui.QDialog()` is not needed and `setpUi()` don't need `ui` reference because you should use `self` (replace `login_window` occurences in `setupUi` and `retranslateUi` with `self`).

Change Your code to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'taco_login.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
     _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
         return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_login_window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("login_window"))
        self.resize(255, 150)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(255, 150))
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(255, 150))
        self.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QDialog#login_window {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.559, y1:0, x2:0.555, y2:1, stop:0.445455 rgba(48, 48, 48, 255), stop:0.859091 rgba(61, 61, 61, 255), stop:1 rgba(79, 79, 79, 255));\n"
"}"))
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
        self.password_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.password_lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 221, 22))
        self.password_lineEdit.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QWidget {border:none;}"))
        self.password_lineEdit.setInputMask(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.password_lineEdit.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.password_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("password_lineEdit"))
        self.login_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.login_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 91, 17))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.login_btn.setPalette(palette)
        self.login_btn.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.login_btn.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QPushButton#login_btn {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}"))
        self.login_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("login_btn"))
        self.username_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.username_lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 221, 22))
        self.username_lineEdit.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QWidget {border:none;}"))
        self.username_lineEdit.setInputMask(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.username_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("username_lineEdit"))
        self.text_1 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.text_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 0, 141, 25))
        self.text_1.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QTextEdit#text_1{\n"
"border: none;\n"
"    background-color: transparent;\n"
"}\n"
""))
        self.text_1.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.text_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("text_1"))
        self.cancel_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.cancel_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 100, 91, 17))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.cancel_btn.setPalette(palette)
        self.cancel_btn.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.cancel_btn.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QPushButton#cancel_btn {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}"))
        self.cancel_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("cancel_btn"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("login_window", "TACO", None))
        self.password_lineEdit.setText(_translate("login_window", "Password", None))
        self.login_btn.setText(_translate("login_window", "Login", None))
        self.username_lineEdit.setText(_translate("login_window", "Username", None))
        self.text_1.setHtml(_translate("login_window", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Sans\'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600; color:#f0f0f0;\">Welcome to TACO!</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.cancel_btn.setText(_translate("login_window", "Cancel", None))

    @QtCore.pyqtSignature("on_cancel_btn_clicked()")
    def Cancel_btn(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_login_window()
    ui.setupUi()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi zetysz, thank you for your reply.

So, I change the object to this:

    class Ui_login_window(QtGui.QDialog):
        def __init__(self):
            QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)

        def setupUi(self, login_window):
            blablabla

include the cancel button to close the apps but it's still not working.

    @QtCore.pyqtSignature("on_cancel_btn_clicked()")
    def Cancel_btn(self):
        self.close()